# Play! 2.3.8 Java - Template check flash content

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I find the following snippet of code on stackoverflow.

In Java Controller:

```
public static Result recoverPassword() {
...
if (!successfullPaswordChange){
    return badRequest(recover.render(resetForm, false));
}

flash("passchange.succces", "Your password was reseted, check your mail");
return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

in the template

```
@if(flash.containsKey("passchange.succces")) {
<div class="alert-message warning">
    <strong>Done!</strong> @flash.get("passchange.succces")
</div>
}
```

But if I use that now, I receive the following error:

**value containsKey is not a member of String**

Is there a way to check the content of a flash message?

Answer (score 0):

You can check direcrly using `@if(flash("passchange.success") != null)`.  Take a look to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash)

Comment: I obtain that error during compilation:      type mismatch;
 found   : String("passchange.success")
 required: Int